# Are debian package update atomic?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, dpkg

I want to update a ubuntu box in an unsupervised way. If the update fails, I'll have to fly there to manually fix it :P so my question is:

If there is power outage in the middle of a kernel or user space package update, will the system stay consistent?

example scenarios:

- update kernel with update-grub atomic or not?
- package A1 and B1 depend on C1. New version A2 and B2 depend on C2 but not C1. The update got A2 and C2 then power outage. What happens? I guess it depends on how dpkg applies the updates after downloads.

Follow up:
if dpkg can't achieve this, what are my options? Things like docker doesn't seem to solve this problem since the host OS still needs to be updated. Thanks!

Added:
what is unsupervised way: I have thousands of these boxes running in various places. Someone can inadvertently unplug at anytime. For upgrade, my server sends them "upgrade to XXX version" command. they execute the command autonomously.

Comment: No it is not even guaranteed  that the system will boot after an update.

Comment: @hek2mgl ... and I don't think that's peculiar to Debian, either. There may be some distro out there where this isn't true, but I think it holds true for the vast majority of them...

Comment: @twalberg If it would be possible to provide that level of stability, Debian would simply have implemented it! ;)

Comment: i thought this is just a tradeoff? most user don't need this guarantee. But in theory, you can always have two copies, then atomically create a new config file specifying the new versions of every upgraded package. Running processes pick up the changes after a reboot.

Comment: If you have thousands in various places, you have redundancy. And if you expect someone to pull plugs, expect worse. You have redundancy already and that's you're safety net.

Comment: @IngoBürk i would give you +1 for the "expect worse" part, but your assumption about redundancy is totally unfounded: having "thousands of these boxes in various places" does not meant that they are all engaged in the same problem space, they just happen to have the same mode of administration.

Comment: They are not in the least atomic. You might want to look into an OS that is _designed_ to be atomic, like [Project Atomic](http://www.projectatomic.io/).

Comment: I have the same question even in 2021.  Has dpkg changed to be fully atomic during these years? I am evaluating if we can rely on dpkg for atomic updates on our Linux based box in case of power outages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean "unsupervised way"? Usually one logs in over ssh, and runs `apt-get` or `aptitude` remotely on the command line. Usually `apt-get/aptitude` runs first, downloading necessary packages. After the download is complete, `dpkg` runs, installing those packages into the system. If there is a system failure while `apt-get/aptitude` are running there is no problem; you are just left with some partially downloaded packages and can resume where you left off. If there is a failure  while `dpkg` is running, there can be (and probably will be) a problem, but the problem is also usually repairable with `dpkg`, using such options as `dpkg --configure`. `dpkg` is reasonably robust. Of course, there are never any guarantees. Bear in mind that the system normally remains up during upgrades, so unless there is some catastrophic problem, like the deletion of important system files, the system will normally remain functional and repairable. Even ssh connections normally persist during an upgrade.

NOTE: Doing updates/upgrades in small increments may reduce the probability of problems. But your mileage may vary.

UPDATE: The poster clarified the term "unsupervised". This probably doesn't make any difference to my answer, except that you would want to make sure you kept logs on all machines, so that in the event of a problem, you would have some idea of what had gone wrong. Debian keeps logs of `dpkg` and `apt`automatically. These are `/var/log/dpkg.log`, `/var/log/apt/history.log`, and `/var/log/apt/term.log`. `term.log` is probably the most relevant in terms of checking whether an upgrade had completed successfully.

Comment: Thanks Faheem. I updated the questions about unsupervised way. But your post seems to have answered me regardless.

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience and the documentation provided by Debian team you should be able to rely on Debian for updating stable systems automatically.

Check https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-uptodate.en.html and evaluate.

If a aptitude gets killed then you will need to manually run

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

I am not saying it is truly safe, but I'd say it is safe enough.

You can achieve a safer configuration by having a really small system as a host to many LXC containers holding most software you will need to upgrade therefore reducing the risk of a system crash when updating the host system.

Comment: thanks for the link. however the doc says "Note that dpkg will install upgrade files in place, even on a running system." So I'm not sure if that can survive power outage.

Comment: I never had problem and I survived power outages and system crashes. I had problems with major version upgrades, specially with missing firmware and major changes like udev or with testing/unstable flavours. Please take read the STABLE as the current stable or old-stable Debian releases.

Comment: Using LXC containers to encapsulate complexity would make the task of updating your host faster and reliable. Having a smaller footprint would make your host system upgrade simpler and faster. If you crash your container you would have to just access the host to fix it.

Comment: make sense. separate complexities into host and LXC and upgrade separately.